# small-bet nextpeer: Allow only one tournament + update tournament name

Tags: objective-c, nextpeer, small-bet

I used [small-bet-nextpeer](https://www.small-bet.com) SDK for real money challenge in game. It shows multiple tournament, how to avoid multiple and add name to one ?

Here is my Small-Bet initialisation code:

```
    [Nextpeer setSmallBetSandboxKey:SMALL_BET_SANDBOX_KEY andProductionKey:SMALL_BET_PRODUCTION_KEY];

    [Nextpeer initializeWithProductKey:NEXT_PEER_GAME_KEY
                          andDelegates:[NPDelegatesContainer containerWithNextpeerDelegate:self notificationDelegate:self tournamentDelegate:self]];
```

Here is Screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got solution.

To avoid multiple tournament, need to check in code:

```
-(BOOL)nextpeerSupportsTournamentWithId:(NSString* )tournamentUuid
{
    if([tournamentUuid isEqualToString:@"NPA23903563215268043"])
        return YES;
    else
        return NO;
}
```

We can edit tournament title in nextpeer website, not in small-bet.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote the SBNPSDK framework.

You have two options:

1. Delete the spare tournaments from the nextpeer website.
2. Implement `-(BOOL)nextpeerSupportsTournamentWithId:(NSString* )tournamentUuid` as Guru suggests. This method is only for filtering nextpeer tournaments from the main interface, it will never ask about small-bet tournaments which all have a `tournamentUuid` starting with `SB`.